# How to resolve a problem "certificate signed by unknown authority" in GKE on pulling image (a private registry) when a pod is created?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl, google-kubernetes-engine

I generated a CA certificate, then issued a certificate based on it for a private registry, that located in the same GKE cluster. Put the server certificates to the private registry and the CA certificate to all GKE nodes and run:

```
update-ca-certificates && systemctl restart docker
```

Images are building and putting into the private registry without problems. When a pod tries to pull the an image from the repository I get an error:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Also I tried to put the CA certificate to the docker `certs.d` directory (10.3.240.100:3000 — the IP address of the private registry) and restart the docker on each node of the GKE cluster, but it doesn't help, too:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/10.3.240.100:3000/ca.cert
```

How to solve this problem? Am I understand correctly that the GKE nodes' docker is responsible for pulling images when creating a pod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem is actual for Kubernetes version `1.19+` and `COS`/`Ubuntu` images based on `containerd` for GKE nodes. Before the 1.19 version Kubernetes used to use `Docker` for building images, but now it uses `containerd`. More details could be found in the official [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/using-containerd).

You need to create and put an CA certificate to each GKE node. Here you can find an answer how to do it correctly https://stackoverflow.com/a/67724696/3319341.

But for `containerd` solution you should replace command

```
nsenter --target 1 --mount systemctl restart docker
```

by

```
nsenter --target 1 --mount systemctl restart containerd
```

A more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990395/3319341

Answer (score 1):

If your on Standard Mode for your GKE cluster, go into Computer Engine > SSH into every node and put into /etc/docker/certs.d/<ip:port>/ca.cert. Create folder if it does not exists.

This works for me. The method will not work for Autopilot Mode.

My exact steps on each node:

```
mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/1.2.3.4:5000  
cd /etc/docker/certs.d/1.2.3.4:5000  
vi /etc/docker/certs.d/1.2.3.4:5000/ca.crt
```

Lastly, create and use the imagepullsecrets in your deployment

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret \ 
--docker-server=1.2.3.4:5000 \
--docker-username='testuser' \
--docker-password='testpassword' \
--docker-email='test@example.com'

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f 
...
 spec:  
   containers:  
   - name: hello  
     image: 1.2.3.4:5000/test:7.12.0  
   imagePullSecrets:  
   - name: my-secret   
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the DaemonSet to load self-signed CAs when using containerd: https://github.com/samos123/gke-node-ca-importer

Credit to @nstogner: https://github.com/samos123/gke-node-ca-importer/commit/756674ee595e1cf86df4b3181bb3cf687bd72c97